# Setting alpha to bitmap in XML drawable not working on API Level 20 and below

Tags: android, android-bitmap, android-selector, xml-drawable

I am setting alpha to a `bitmap` in `XML` (selector) and its working fine on `API level 23 , 22 , 21` but its doesn't work on `API level 20` and below `API levels`.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!--State Selected-->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/item_selected" android:state_selected="true"/>
<!--State Normal-->
 <item >
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/item_selected" android:alpha="0.6"/>
</item>
```

**Edit**

Please suggest me some alternatives to do this by using `XML`.

Comment: Yes, I have edited the xml in question.

Comment: you mean in `integer`?

Comment: I tried, its not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112860/discussion-between-ashish-tiwari-and-janki-gadhiya).

Comment: Why don't you try using `android:tint` instead of `alpha`.

Comment: Ok, trying to use it.

Comment: `android:tint`is also not working, I got this link https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=180422

Comment: @AshishTiwari Have you tried it to set Programatically ?

Comment: @jaydroider No I haven't try it programatically, I have to set it by using xml selectors.

Answer (score 2):

Setting `alpha` programmatically will work. Try this.

I have tried your selector as the background of this `ImageView`:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/select"
    />
```

My java code :

```
imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setAlpha(0.5f);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+imageView.isSelected()
                    , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(imageView.isSelected())
            {
                imageView.setSelected(false);
                // set alpha 0.5
                imageView.setAlpha(0.5f);
            }
            else {
                imageView.setSelected(true);
                // set alpha 1
                imageView.setAlpha(1f);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Okay.. I am checking

Comment: I am not creating click listener of Image as `ImageView` is used in custom `layout` of  `TabLayout`.

Comment: The put this in `OnTabChanged()`. Set the alpha for current tab as `1` and all other tabs with `0.5`.

Answer (score 1):

bitmap element's alpha attribute was added at API 21
so there is no way setting alpha in the xml.
you could set alpha using the code according to Janki Gadhiya's answer.